# htaccess random redirect to random url

Tags: .htaccess

is it somehow possible to randomly redirect purely in htaccess? (without need of php)
Something like:

```
rand_pool() = ['a.php', 'b.php', 'c.php'] 
RewriteRule ^page.php$ /rand_pool() [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) directive for this.

First you need to generate a map file:

```
## random.map -- rewriting map
randomX   a.php|b.php|c.php
```

You can generate as many values (separated by `|`) as needed, however I don't know if there is any limit in apache regarding their count.

Then you define the *Randomized Plain Text* type of rewrite map using this file and finally use it in your rewrite rule.

```
RewriteMap randomMap rnd:/path/to/random.map
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ /${randomMap:randomX} [P,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, at least not with any amount of efficiency. One might be able to abuse mod_unique_id to generate an unique id, then reduce this id to a new page, but this is at best dodgy.

Instead internally rewrite to a router page, then perform the necessary redirect on this page. When maintaining the code, it will be much more clear what you wanted to achieve with this.